# Build issues with Visual Studio 11

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, rc, build-error

I am building a simple program on VS 11 Professional beta edition.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

But I am getting RC errors.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Stephen, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 5/23/2012 8:31:30 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\Stephen.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  Source.cpp
1>RC : fatal error RC1106: invalid option: -ologo
1>  
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.67
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I just compile the source file alone (i.e., not building the project), it compiles. I googled on this error but didn't find much useful information. I have seen the compiler and linker properties. No, where `-ologo` option is seen. I amn't sure where this invalid option is coming from.

I have VS 2005, 2010 installed on my system. Does this has anything to do with this error ? Any help is aprreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to `project` -> `Properties` -> `Configuration Properties` -> `General`. Change the platform toolset to the correct toolset you are using. Or just change [Suppress Startup Banner to 'no'](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/499476/c-project-resource-compiler-fails-with-rc-fatal-error-rc1106-invalid-option-ologo).

Comment: Platform toolset is **Visual Studio 11 (v110)** which is correct. Even then I am getting the error. I will try the other option and let you know.

Comment: Setting startup banner to No didn't either solve the problem. It gave me a warning `cl : Command line warning D9035: option 'nologo-' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release` instead and gave the same error.

Comment: @user731676 Did you read the linked article it looks like there is a problem with having an earlier version of the Windows SDK installed and gives some possible fixes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are migrating your sourcecode from 32-bit to 64-bit platform and you encounter this error during build, do the following:

1. Select your Project on the Solutions explorer.
2. From menu, select Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories
3. On "Executable Directories", check if "$(WindowsSdkDir)\bin" exist -
   Check first what is "WindowsSdkDir" by clicking the down arror->edit->click "Macros" button and see where it is pointing...
   Usually it is in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin"
4. Check if there are executable files under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin"
5. If none, then there could be folders under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin"
6. Go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86" and check if "RC.exe" exist
7. If "RC.exe" exist then go back to Step 1, Step 2.
8. On "Executable Directories", change "$(WindowsSdkDir)\bin" to "$(WindowsSdkDir)\bin\x86"
9. Click "Apply" then "Ok" button.
10. Rebuild your project and that should solve your problem.