# Visual Studio 2012 "LINK : fatal error RC1106: invalid option: -ologo"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I have a problem when I try to build console application in Vusual Studio 2012.
The problem is that I get the following Error: "LINK : fatal error RC1106: invalid option: -ologo".

When I change "Platform Toolset" from project properties to v90 (is is by default v110) it works.
It works only for v90 and for the rest I have the same error.

I appritiate for help.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build issues with Visual Studio 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729777/build-issues-with-visual-studio-11)

Comment: Thanks Jehof i found the answer to my problem using your aid

Answer (score 0):

The latest SDK i have is v8.0A. So I set to Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A.

Don't forget to backup your file prior doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2015 I simply retargeted from SDK Windows 10 to 8.1 and it worked. I was working in c++